# accessing elements of std::vector when passing by reference

Tags: c++, vector, pass-by-reference

Is there an easier way to access element of a vector when it is passed by reference? This will work but it seems overly complicated. Thanks for the help in advance!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void my_func(std::vector<int> * vect){
    // this will not work
    cout << *vect[2] << endl;
    // this will work
    cout << *(vect->begin()+2) << endl;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> vect = {1,3,4,56};
    my_func(&vect) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's pass by pointer, not pass by reference. Your C++ textbook should explain the difference in an early chapter.

Comment: Try using `void my_func(std::vector<int> & vect)` and simply use `cout << vect[2] << endl;`

Comment: `// this will not work` That's because you have to dereference it first before accessing index. Use parentheses to explicitly define the order of evaluation `cout << (*vect)[2] << endl;`

Comment: You're passing by pointer, not by reference.   They're different.   In any event, the approach is `(*vect)[2]` due to rules of operator precedence.  `*vect[2]` is equivalent to `*(vect[2])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, you're passing a *pointer* to the vector.

To pass by reference you do:

```
void my_func(std::vector<int>& vect) ...
```

Then it's as simple as doing `vect[index]` to access an element.

And usually when you pass a container by reference, you would also want to specify `const` so as to not accidentally modify the contents inside of it. Unless of course, you intentionally want to.